How would you fix a bone which deforms the mesh rather than simply rotating or bending it?
I ran into a snag while trying to rig this low poly character (I didn't model it, it's a practice model I downloaded). The mesh is deformed whenever I try to bend the bones:


Is this normal? Did I do something wrong and what is it?

Hello could you please share your file?

Maybe apply the scale of your armature in Object mode, if it doesn't work, please share your file

@moonboots
Sure thing! I’ll have to get my computer running though to get the file, I’m currently replying on my iPad.

How exactly do I do that on a comment? Or should I just edit the post directly.

Like I said, I'm fairly new to rigging in Blender, I'm new to Stack Exchange, I have literally no idea what I'm doing.

do what on a comment exactly? What I suggested is selecting your armature in Object mode and apply the scale (Ctrl A), does it work?

Ok, I'll try that.

I was asking how to share a blend file on here. It isn't a supported file like images are.

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

oh thank you! Probably should've gone looking for that. Ugh, I'm such a newbie to all of this.

So did applying the scale fix your problem?

Haven’t tried. I’ve been pretty busy, but I should be able to test it out tomorrow. Thanks for the help either way! And sorry for taking up so much of your time.

@moonboots it worked! Thank you!!!

You've scaled your armature in Object mode but haven't applied the scale, so just apply the scale (CtrlA)
